# Delegate Func<> in windows form application C#

Tags: c#, forms, delegates, func

The following code works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Func<string, string>> mylist = new List<Func<string, string>>();

        mylist.Add(Navigation);
        mylist.Add(Tactic);
        Func<string, string> GameOfThrones = mylist[0];
        string name = "NONE";
        Console.WriteLine(GameOfThrones(name));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static string Navigation(string tmp) { return "Navigation"; }
    private static string Tactic(string tmp) { return "Tactic"; }
}
```

But i wish to use this with an windows form application not console.

I tried the following, but I can't get it to work:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Func<string, string>> mylist = new List<Func<string, string>>();

    mylist.Add(Navigation);
    mylist.Add(Tactic);
    Func<string, string> SkillCall = mylist[0];
    string name ="NONE";
    TextBox1.Text = SkillCall(name);
}       
        private static string Navigation(string tmp) { return "Navigation"; }
        private static string Tactic(string tmp) { return "Tactic"; }
}
```

Error   8   'mylist' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: The code is odd but fine. My guess is you have an extraneous brace or semi-colon somewhere in your local copy.

Comment: Solution..

Apparently VS is satisfied with me copy all the code in the class and paste it into a new dublicate class..

If anyone can explain this without using "That's M$" then you'll get the solved mark.

Comment: Unless you post all relevant code files, it would be difficult to suggest why it was not compiling.

Comment: This is all the relevant code, which makes it even more annoying.. The above code is copy/pasted directly from the project files..

Answer (score 2):

Your Windows forms version makes use of a [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to allow the forms designer (in visual studio) to edit the code (`InitializeComponent` function, etc.) as you design the form without messing with your custom code and handlers (like `button1_Click`).

Any chance that the other class definition (probably in Form1.Designer.cs file) includes a field named mylist?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on C# 3.5+ (and have targetted that framework) then...
There is nothing wrong with that code - the error must be somewhere else, or you have changed it for brevity or whatever. Please list the existing code, or step through and see where your error is.